# Dúvida sobre modularização em javascript

Tags: javascript

Já há um tempo que vejo em códigos, inclusive de grandes bibliotecas Javascript, trechos mais ou menos assim:

```
if (module.exports) {
    // faça algo
}

//#####
define({/* parametros */})

//#####
import algumacoisa from biblioteca

//#####
var foo = require('biblioteca')
// aqui, foo já é um objeto com metodos da biblioteca
foo.bar();
```

Enfim... Eu percebi que tudo isso está relacionado à modularização. No NodeJS eu sei que isso é usado (não programo em Node). O que eu não entendi é isso sendo usado em front-end/client-side.
Isso seria promovido por algum tipo de transpiler? Ou é nativo? Porque eu testei muitos desses atributos em navegadores atualizados e tudo retornou `false` ou `undefined`. Até pensei estar relacionado ao Ecmascript 6, mas como eu disse, os navegadores não parecem suportar isso nativamente.

Obrigado.

Comment: Essas grandes bibliotecas que citou são do NodeJS? Ou algum outro framework?